# wordpressL How to array the child categories without any html tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

I am using a category called 'blogs'. Under that category I have many authors. Each author gets a category for himself.

In the 'blogs' template I want to display nicely a  for each category and the ecxerpt from the latest post.

Unfortunately, when I am trying to use wp_list_categories to query the child of that 'blogs' cat, I get a html code of list. I can't use it.

Any Ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

You need to specify child_of and retrieve the id of 'blogs'